# Fix temporal gauge $A_0=f$ using an appropriate gauge transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Consider the Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}= -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} - A_{\mu}J^{\mu} \ \ \ \  \text{ with } \ \ \ \  F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}.
\end{equation}
The current $J^{\mu}$ is conserved and hence it satisfies $\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0$.

I showed action $S$ is invariant under the gauge transformation     \begin{equation}
    A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \alpha,
    \end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary function that vanishes at infinity.
Moreover I know that the equations of motions are
$$\partial^{\mu}F_{\mu \nu} = J_{\nu}.$$

**Question: Show that one can choose the function $\alpha$ so that after an appropriate gauge transformation
one can set $A_0=f$, where $f$ is a given function.**

I think I'm missing some fundamental stuff about gauge theory since e.g. I don't know why the coulomb gauge or the lorenz gauge are allowed.
Anyways..

**My idea:**
Say $\alpha = \int (f- A_0) dt$, then we get under the gauge transformation .
$$A_0 \to A_0' = A_0 + \partial_{0}  \int (f- A_0) dt =  A_0 +f - A_0 = f.$$
And then we redefine $A_0'$ as $A_0$ which is possible by gauge invariance and therefore obtain $A_0=f$.

Is what I'm doing correct, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
Moreover, what would the residual gauge transformation be?

Comment: Are you sure $A^0$ can be set to *any* function $f$?

Comment: well that's the question.  Of course in physics we don't consider non-integrable functions e.g.  everything is always smooth. or is that not the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the gauge field $A'_{\mu}$ does not satisfy the desired property, so let's say instead $A'_{0} = g$ for some function $g$.  Choose $\alpha$ such that
$$
\partial_0 \alpha = f-g,
$$
which is guaranteed to have a solution.
We apply a gauge transformation $A'_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} = A'_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \alpha $ and obtain that
$$
A_0 = A'_0 + \partial_0 \alpha  = g + f-g  =f.
$$
Therefore after an appropriate gauge transformation one can set $A_0=f$.  Of course if we'd apply another gauge transformation such that $\partial_0 \alpha =0$ and we'd still have that $A_0=f$. So the residual gauge symmetry is $\partial_0\alpha =0$.